# How to grep the alphanumeric part from a text file

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have a file with following content:

```
some text
some text
Implementation-Version: 1.1.1
some text
```

When I use:

```
grep Implementation-Version filename
```

so my output is **Implementation-Version: 1.1.1**

How can I get only the Version number 1.1.1?

Answer (score 2):

You can use awk like that:

```
grep Implementation-Version filename | awk  -v FS=': ' '{print $NF}'
```

Or, without using `grep` at all:

```
awk '$1=="Implementation-Version:" {print $2}' filename
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. But if I want to use the version number for other purposes, I get a "?" Character at the end, e.g. with touch $ (grep ..) I get 1.1.1?_20210413 instead of 1.1.1_20210413 as output.
Doesn't grep cut the version number exactly?

Comment: `touch "$(grep Implementation-Version filename | awk  -v FS=': ' '{print $NF}')"` creates `1.1.1`, there is no `?` in its name.

Comment: strange. For me it creates a "?" at the end. If I auto-complete the file with TAB on console, the file is even called 1.1.1^M. I do not understand that.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Po 'Implementation-Version: \K.*' file
```

or

```
grep -Po '(?<=Implementation-Version: ).*' file
```

Output:

```
1.1.1
```

See: `man grep` and [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 1):

With sed

```
sed '/Implementation-Version: /!d;s///' file
```

Comment: that works, but I when use it in bash script like version=$(sed '/Implementation-Version: /!d;s///' file), cp myfile.txt myfile_${version}_$(date ...).txt I'm getting as result myfile_1.1.1?_20210417. Note the "?" at end of version. Do you know why?

Comment: @ng-User A lot of time the system use the question mark when it find a char that it know nothing about. Try to see with cat -A file if there is a char like that at the end of the version line.

Answer (score 1):

Another `sed` variation would be:

```
sed -n 's/^Implementation-Version:\s*//p' file
```

Where the normal substitution form `'s/find/replace/'` is used along with the `-n` option to suppress normal printing of pattern space and `p` following the substitution to output after a successful substitution.

The `find` part anchor `"Implementation-Version:"` to the beginning of the line with the circumflex character `'^'`. The `\s+` matches zero-or-more whitespace characters that follow. Then on a successful match, the content is replaced with nothing, effectively trimming the beginning of the line though the final space leaving your desired output.

**Example Use/Output**

With your example text in the file named `content`, you would have:

```
$ sed -n 's/^Implementation-Version:\s*//p' content
1.1.1
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

With default `grep` and `cut`:

```
grep Implementation-Version file | cut -d " " -f2
```

Or with a line of `awk`:

```
awk '{ if ($1 == "Implementation-Version:") print $2 }' file
```

Output:

```
1.1.1
```